# Styling output of Object in Typescript react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have an object output that looks like this:

```
name: "James Charles"
address: "<font face="Arial" size="2">10109 New York. Ste. C, New York NY</font>"
phone: "784-247-7926"
email: "jamescharles@yahoo.com"
```

I'm doing this in my `render()`:

```
<ul>
    {(Object as any).entries(this.state.DocList).map((object, i) => <li>{object}</li>)}
</ul>
```

However, the output is displaying something like this:

```
nameJames Charles
address<font face="Arial" size="2">10109 New York. Ste. C, New York NY</font>
phone784-247-7926
emailjamescharles@yahoo.com
```

I'm trying to style up the output to add for example a space between the key and value, a semi colon, maybe a span class so I can bold the key fields.

How can I get more control of the output? And what would be the best way to strip the html from the address field so it's not displaying it in the address?

So that my output looks similar to this:

- **Name:** James Charles
- **Address:** 10109 New York. Ste. C, New York NY
- **Phone:** 784-247-7926
- **Email:** jamescharles@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: to isolate the address you need regex, try: `(?<=>)[a-zA-Z ,.0-9]*(?=<)` (if that doesn't work in your browser or environment, try omitting the positive lookbehind at the begging `(?<=>)`)

Next: When using `Object.entries` the return value is going to be in the format `[key, value]` so instead of saying this:

```
<ul>
    {(Object as any).entries(this.state.DocList).map((object, i) => <li>{object}</li>)}
</ul>
```

Try this:

```
<ul>
    {(Object as any).entries(this.state.DocList).map(([key, value], i) => 
    <li>
        <span>{key}: </span><span>{value}</span>
    </li>)}
</ul>
```

The difference here is that in the `map` callback, you're destructuring the arguments (`key, and value`) from the array -- this is beneficial so that you can utilize them independently.

Comment: wow! thank you such much.. this really helped me. With regex would I be doing this in the function where I create the object?

Comment: I was able to do it with `.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "" ); ` Thank you again for everything.

Comment: @hisusu32 no problem, glad I could help :)